# Regex for email not validating numbers in the high level domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation, regex-negation

```
 private const string EmailPattern = @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z";
```

I am able to validate most of the emails correctly but one of the condition that I want to validated is numeric digit at the end of the high level domain.
eg : abc@test.com1 (I dont think this is a valid email and want to validate this condition)

There are lot of regex tht I have tried but no success.

Comment: count back from the end until you hit a `.`, then test that section for numbers. That is litterally all you can do

Comment: Add `(?<!\d\Z)` after `\Z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex

```
^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$
```